# Displaying results on separate page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a beginner question. What is the easiest way to take data from a form on one html page and display it on another when the user clicks submit? I have two functions, a Submit() that calls the display() function (the display function displays the data on the page). I first displayed the result on the index.html page but realized it was too cluttered so I opted to print the results to a separate html page. However, I cannot recall the proper way of doing this. I tried putting location.href='results.html' inside my display() function by it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use just HTML + Javascript to achieve this.

Just create a form with `method="get"`. So the values will be passed by querystring to the another page.

Example:

#### index.html

```
<html>
    <form method="get" action="results.html">
        <input type="text" name="age" />
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
</html>
```

#### results.html

```
<html>  
    <h1></h1>

    <script>
        document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = window.location.search.substring(1);
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Whilst technically this is possible using [HTML5 local storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp), the best solution to your question is to use a server side language such as PHP, which you can read up on [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/) as a beginners tutorial, or in more detail on the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/index.php)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. Write your html page (e.g. "index.html") like

```
<html>
<head>
<title>form with output</title>
</head>
<body>
<form target="out" action="tst.php">
<input type="text" name="a">
<input type="text" name="b">
<input type="submit" name="sub" value="OK">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and, assuming you have PHP available on your webserver you can write a second (php) script (filename: "tst.php") like this

```
<?php
echo json_encode($_REQUEST);
?>
```

(The php script simply outputs all passed variables as a JSON string). The important thing that will redirect your form's output into a separate window is the `target="out"` part in the `<form>` tag.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this with JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, you can also redirect to a javascript driven page (filetype: .html). In this case you must extract the passed arguments from the pag's url by doing `argstring=window.location.search`. The first character in this string will be a `?`. After that you will find the agruments and their values in url encoded fashion.

Comment: Would that go in my display() function?

Comment: You need to "send" the form in some way or use something like AJAX to transfer the variables and their values to the target page. Alternatively you could also open a new window by using the old `window.open()` method (supplying the arguments after a `?` which you will have to extract from the form manually). I don't know what your "display()" function does.